# Is there a section where to ask for organizing a programmer team?

Tags: discussion

Have a look to the following method:
It's hard to understand what is the Single Responsibility accomplished by this method and the difference with his caller:  GetDetailForEvent.
Who is _client? Does the word new refer to the lack of the event in the cache?

**Would you discourage this kind of code in your team?**
Can I open this question or is not constructive?

```
    private void GetDetailForNewEvent(int @event)
    {
        lock (_eventDetails)
        {
            if (!_eventDetails.ContainsKey(@event))
            {
                _eventDetails[@event] = _client.GetEventDetail(@event);

                //TODO: what is the following instruction for???
                _eventDetailsLock[@event] = new object();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: one may argue that conceptually, questions like this have been addressed in [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/141010/31260)

Comment: @gnat: I've answered that question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/258185/114829. But I think there is a huge difference of abstraction between my actual question here and that one. Can you look to the text of my actual question (the title can be fuorviating, probably I should change it).

Comment: the difference doesn't look substantial. If your question was more concrete, with more of a real code, it could probably make it into CR (you'd have to ensure that it meets [their six-yes requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to be posted there)

Comment: @gnat: thanks.. I would like to ask a question, but it's not a polemic. Since you (as a community) refuse a lot of kind of questions I wonder if you already have too many questions and also which kind of questions are you looking for.. how is going this section? (it's really not a critic, I'm just looking for info)

Comment: you can take a look at [recent open questions tagged coding-style](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bcoding-style%5d%20closed%3ano) to find out what kind tends to fly well

Comment: @gnat: Thanks.. Looking at those questions I think the problem with my question is that it's not very clear.. and opinion based for how I formulated it.. and also it's not clear what kind of answer I expect from the community.. I think it could maybe fit the community, but my score is too low to try..

Comment: The title led me to think that you are looking to hire some developers. I'd never have guessed that it's a code quality question.